# Testacular does not run e2e test

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angular-scenario

Once again I have problems running my angularJS e2e test with testacular. This time the output is

```
Chrome 23.0: Executed 0 of 13 (skipped 13) SUCCESS (0.117 secs / 0 secs)
info: Disconnecting all browsers
```

no test are run, here is my config file.

```
basePath = './';

files = [
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
    ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
    'e2e/*.js'
];

autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

singleRun = true;

proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:8080/'
};
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I just tried it with ChromeCanary and I got Chrome 26.0: Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (2.119 secs / 1.29 secs) info: Disconnecting all browsers Then I ran it in firefox: $.\scripts\e2e-test.bat info: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/ info (launcher): Starting browser Firefox info (Firefox 18.0): Connected on socket id UYYPyXotuajK3OEmTV3_ Firefox 18.0: Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (1.555 secs / 1.152 secs) info: Disconnecting all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, here is a solution for this problem. I posted this question in angular google groups and here is the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/testacular/fumqhOAEH3s it was a bug and it is fixed by the author.